# Filter models by related model field in Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django

I have two models: adverisement_campaign and advertisement_view (log of views). Every advertisement campaign must be displayed to the user no more frequently than once every X days. So, campaign model has field with number of days.
I need to select campaigns, which has not been displayed to user more than number of days for this campaign. And get random campaign from this list to display user.
So, I wrote query, which select campaigns, have not seen yet.

```
user_campaigns = AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user)
                                        .values('advertisement_id')\
                                        .annotate(datetime_last=Max('datetime'))\
                                        .values_list('advertisement_id')
```

But now I need to filter campaigns to show user campaign, which he has not seen more than X days, specified for each company. Something like this

```
user_campaigns = AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user, **datetime_last__gte=asdvertisement.days_between_shows**)
                                        .values('advertisement_id')\
                                        .annotate(datetime_last=Max('datetime'))\
                                        .values_list('advertisement_id')
```

How can I do this filtering with Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Something like should do the trick:

```
user_campaigns = AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user, 
 **datetime_last__gte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_between_shows))
                                        .values('advertisement_id')\
                                        .annotate(datetime_last=Max('datetime'))\
                                        .values_list('advertisement_id')
```